# shortest path in two-dimensional array using C

Tags: c, shortest-path

I want to find a shortest path from (0,0) to (6,6) but i don't know how to do it using C. -1 is the way I can go, and -2 is the way I can't go. 0 is starting point and -3 is ending point.
Please help..

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define VERTICES 7

int maze[VERTICES][VERTICES] = {
{  0, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
{ -1, -2, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2 },
{ -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },
{ -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1 },
{ -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1 },
{ -1, -2, -1, -2, -2, -2, -1 },
{ -1, -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -3 } };

int A[VERTICES][VERTICES];

printA(int n)
{
int i, j;
printf("===============================\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%3d", A[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
printf("===============================\n");
}
void solve(int n)
{
int i, j, k=0;
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j<n; j++)
        A[i][j] = maze[i][j];

while (1)
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (A[i][j] == k)
            {
                if (0 <= i + 1 < n && 0 <= j < n && A[i + 1][j] == -1)
                    A[i + 1][j] = k + 1;
                if (0 <= i - 1 < n && 0 <= j < n && A[i - 1][j] == -1)
                    A[i - 1][j] = k + 1;
                if (0 <= i < n && 0 <= j + 1 < n && A[i][j + 1] == -1)
                    A[i][j + 1] = k + 1;
                if (0 <= i < n && 0 <= j - 1 < n && A[i][j - 1] == -1)
                    A[i][j - 1] = k + 1;
                if (A[i][j] == -3)
                    break;
            }
    }
    k++;
}
printf("%d\n", k);
printA(VERTICES);
}

main()
{
solve(VERTICES);
}
```

Comment: It is not good to omit type of return value unless you are using too-old compiler.

Comment: Try googling "breadth first search c".

Comment: Maybe [Lee algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm)?

Comment: @Tomer Or [Dijkstra](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/)?

Comment: Thank you all but I can't apply BFS and Dijkstra in here and I can't find lee algorithm..I'm almost new in C..T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, this should be a commend but i do not have enough reputation.. Anyways:

You could also look for the a* (a-star) Algorithm to solve your problem there are heaps of implementations and descriptions available e.g.:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577457-a-star-shortest-path-algorithm/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9880/Very-simple-A-algorithm-implementation

heyes-jones.com/astar.php

Answer (score 0):

As Jan Raufelder suggested, you could use the A* algorithm, which stands as the best compromise between quickness and accuracy and is widely used in video games. However, there are cases for which A* will deliver the shortest path after quite a long time, and these worst case scenarii mostly appear for mazes.

```
███████████████████████  In this case,
██ S       1 ██ E    ██  A* will start at S,
██   █████████████   ██  explore branch 1,
██            2 ██   ██  then branch 2,
██   █████████████   ██  and then branch 3,
██            3 ██   ██  before taking branch 4
██   █████████████   ██  to finally get to E.
██            4      ██  It still gives you the shortest path,
███████████████████████  but it takes a huge time.
```

If you want a more robust and generally faster solution, you could try to convert your maze into a graph (vertices and edges), and apply a Dijkstra algorithm on it. But that implies you redo everything you have done so far, and take some time to think about how you are going to build your maze in memory, because it won't simply be a 2D-array of `int`.